# What is the best practice for checking each url visited in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension I want to to check each url against a list of possible urls and then perform an action if one of the possible urls is visited. For example if Amazon.com was on the list then anytime a user went to Amazon.com the action would be performed.

There are around 5000 possible urls which are all in a mySQL database and can be outputted to a JSON file.

Should the extension check each url everytime a page is visited by checking the JSON file? Is there anyway of loading the JSON file into the extension? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two options, depending on the action you'd like to take when a particular URL is visited:

1. You can encode your filter in a JavaScript object that you load into the extension's background page at startup. The KMOO extension is a good example of how this might work: https://code.google.com/p/chrome-opt-out-extension/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fchrome
2. If you're injecting content scripts, you can restrict your extension directly in the manifest by adding appropriate filters. See the `matches` attribute at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html for example.

The first option is probably what I'd recommend. Parsing a large JSON object into a lookup table once at startup isn't terribly expensive, and certainly better than reading it every time you'd like to make a decision.